# Trying to convert from lowercase to uppercase and viceversa. strange result using .toUpperCase()

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm a real noob and my question may be stupid.

I'm building an app to convert from uppercase to lowercase and vice versa.
I have two editText and 2 buttons.
One editText is the user input and the other is the converted text; one button is to convert to lowercase and the other is to convert to uppercase.
this is my .xml so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="myapplication.example.falcoleo.lettercaseconverter.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
android:orientation="vertical">




<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_originalText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/grey800"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/originalText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:gravity="top"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSetToUppercase"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="convertToUpperCase" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="convertToLowerCase" />
</LinearLayout>



<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_convertedText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/grey800"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">


        <EditText
            android:text="TEST"
            android:id="@+id/convertedText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:editable="false"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:background="#00000000"
            />


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

it's far from perfect but the real problem lies in the .java

```
package myapplication.example.falcoleo.lettercaseconverter;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    TextView textView;
    Button copyText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.convertedText); //the second editText is called textView
        final TextView original =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.originalText); //the first editTExt is called original

        final String upper = original.toString().toUpperCase(); //Convert to uppercase
        final String lower = original.toString().toLowerCase(); //Convert to lowercase


        Button convertToUpperCase=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSetToUppercase);  // il primo pulsante si chiama convertToUpperCase
        convertToUpperCase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView.setText(upper);//Set Text on button click via this function.
            }
        });

        Button convertToLowerCase = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSetToUppercase);  // il secondo pulsante si chiama convertToLowerCase
        convertToLowerCase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView.setText(lower); //Set Text on button click via this function.

            }
        });

    }
}
```

When I build the app it doesn't give any error.
If I run it on a device, when I tap the convertToLowerCase button it does nothing; and when i tap convertToUpperCase button it writes `android.support.v7.widget.appcompatedittext{28f38fb7 vfed..cl......i. 0,0-0,0 #7f0c006b app:id/originaltext}` on the convertedText EditText.
Nothing to see on the log.
What is it doing? i'm not even sure it is an error message.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following

```
final String upper = original.getText().toString().toUpperCase(); //Convert to uppercase
final String lower = original.getText().toString().toLowerCase(); //Convert to lowercase
```

Comment: Now it just clears the lower editText when i tap the buttons

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that might be causing you problems is the element type;

You are referencing :

```
TextView original;
```

But the actual elements are:

```
EditText
```

Can you please fix those first then try?

Then make sure once you get the typed text, convert to String and perhaps check for empty strings?

I hope this helps!

Comment: Do i have to do `final EditText original =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.originalText);
        final EditText  textView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.convertedText); ` ? as i said i'm a noob.

Comment: This is basic android. If you are using EditTextt in your xml file, you have to reference them as such. You cannot use TextView when you need EditText.